# How to solve this JavaScript problem?

Tags: javascript, navigation, validation

When I go to http://www.kambariokas.eu/prideti.php, I get an error **$("#nav").spasticNav is not a function.**
In other pages this script works perfectly, but this isn't a script for validation. Maybe you have suggestions how to solve this?
Here is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#nav').spasticNav();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.validator.addMethod("username", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9\_]+$/i.test(value);
            }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, or underscore.");

            $("#skelbimas").validate();

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because $("#nav").spasticNav is not a function. That is, you haven't defined it anywhere.

I presume it should be defined in the file http://www.kambariokas.eu/%20dizainas/js/jquery.spasticNav.js but that returns a 404 error. Hence your spasticNav function is never defined anywhere.

Edit: remove the extra space before dizainas to correct the script location.

Comment: oh, dummy mistake :) Thx ;) but this haven't solved the problem